# Having trouble changing character set in terminal

Tags: debian, sudo, set

The GNU/Linux terminal doesn't display Swedish characters (sv_SE.UTF-8). I've googled, and found several sources with various solutions.

To summarize the error, no matter what guide I follow, is that I get a variation of this: "locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory".

I'm using Raspbian (Debian 9)

The one thing that worked was:

```
sudo locale-gen 
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

However, when rebooting, I'm back at the terminal not being able to display Swedish characters.

Comment: which terminal?

Comment: A question that talks about a terminal (albeit without identifying which one) not displaying characters and then mentions nothing at all about the configuration _of the terminal_.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with Ukrainian language. Execute

```
locale
```

and check `LC_ALL=` variable, probably it's just empty.

The workaround can be pretty simple:

```
sudo update-locale LC_ALL=sv_SE.UTF-8 LANG=sv_SE.UTF-8
```

Check content of the `/etc/default/locale` file afterwards, it should be

```
LANG=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=sv_SE.UTF-8
```

If nothing helps, just add this lines manually to the file `/etc/default/locale`.

Finally reboot your computer.

Comment: **`dpkg-reconfigure locales`** is supposed to do that (when it asks what the default locale should be).

Comment: Supposed and does are two different things, especially in Linux.